# Tablespace does not exist after creating

Tags: sql, oracle, docker

i have a problem, i have .sql file with commands using docker-compose and a oracle database. Im trying to initialize a database with image: gvenzl/oracle-xe:latest

```
CREATE
TABLESPACE DATA_PROD DATAFILE 'DBProd.dbf'
SIZE 20M AUTOEXTEND ON next 1M maxsize 600M
DEFAULT STORAGE (INITIAL 1M NEXT 1M MINEXTENTS 1
MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED PCTINCREASE 0);

Create user IO identified by IO;
Grant create session to IO ;
Grant create table to IO ;
Grant create trigger to IO ;
Grant create sequence to IO ;

alter user IO default tablespace DATA_PROD;
alter user IO quota unlimited on DATA_PROD;
```

And in docker this pops up

```
2023-07-10 11:21:15 CONTAINER: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/V1_INIT.sql ...
2023-07-10 11:21:48 Tablespace created.
2023-07-10 11:21:55 User created.
2023-07-10 11:21:55 Grant succeeded.
2023-07-10 11:21:55 Grant succeeded.
2023-07-10 11:21:55 Grant succeeded.
2023-07-10 11:21:55 Grant succeeded.
2023-07-10 11:21:55 alter
2023-07-10 11:21:55 *
2023-07-10 11:21:55 ERROR at line 1:
2023-07-10 11:21:55 ORA-65048: error encountered when processing the current DDL statement in
2023-07-10 11:21:55 pluggable database XEPDB1
2023-07-10 11:21:55 ORA-00959: tablespace 'DATA_PROD' does not exist
2023-07-10 11:21:55 alter
2023-07-10 11:21:55 *
2023-07-10 11:21:55 ERROR at line 1:
2023-07-10 11:21:55 ORA-65048: error encountered when processing the current DDL statement in
2023-07-10 11:21:55 pluggable database XEPDB1
2023-07-10 11:21:55 ORA-00959: tablespace 'DATA_PROD' does not exist
```

I have tried some stackoverflow answers on similar topics

Comment: This is not reproducible in my local Oracle 19 XE running in docker. Are you sure that all the above statements except `alter user` executed successfully?

Comment: try either putting the full path for the file name or removing it altogether (probably the better solution, as usually for a CDB, the oracle-managed-filenames is the best practice, and in this case, do not specify a filename for tablespaces...;)

Comment: I have tried removing this DATAFILE '.dbf' but couldnt execute this query @gsalem

Do you mean creating tablespace is wrong written?

Comment: In docker logs it shows that tablespace is created

Comment: Are these lines in the same script or do you run them one after the other via something?

Comment: In the same .sql file i run it by docker-compose

Comment: Can you edit your question to show us the log produced by this script?

Comment: Can you check in the DB on which 'level' the tablespace is created: CDB or PDB?

Comment: Also please add an entry point shell script

Comment: Im using docker-compose if thats what are you asking
  oracle-xe:
    image: gvenzl/oracle-xe:latest
    container_name: oracle
    ports:
      - "1521:1521"
    environment:
      - ORACLE_PASSWORD=oracle
    volumes:
      - ../database/scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

Comment: Have you tried select * from sys.dba_tablespaces connected exactly to that database which raises that exception? Could it be that a pluggable database does not see that tablespace you created in some other database?

Comment: @BogdanDincescu yes i have tried and there is a table space named like that